# Relationship between DOM "style" property and actual CSS styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an element to which I've (directly) applied several CSS properties. After the element is processed by the DOM, I've tried inspecting its `style` property object and saw all values (including color) are empty strings. Was rather surprised by this.

What's the purpose of the `style` property for DOM elements? Is it to store styles defined `dynamically`? I've seen people do things, in jQuery like:

```
$('#el').removeAttr('style');
```

which I guess the browser interprets as `removeProp('style')` which cancelled out all styles applied to an element and removed the initial styles by the CSS file.

Comment: removing an attribute doesn't remove the property on DOM node

Comment: *"which I guess the browser interprets as"* - your browser does not interpret your intent, it behaves according to specifications. also, jquery is an external library, not part of the browser.

Comment: Here's the thing I don't get...the style property contains values in the style attribute. Does a library like jQuery, when you do $('el'.).css('property', 'value') modifies this style property in the background so it's like you've manually added style="property:value" to your element?

Comment: Yes, `.css()` does exactly that when writing, but when reading, it falls back to `getComputedStyle`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consult documentation on properties if they do not do what you expect.

MDN [Element.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) article describes what it actually does. It also mentions how to achieve what you want to do.

As for the removal, try the following on the browser console, step by step:

```
let el = document.querySelector("body")
el.style.color = "#fff"
el.getAttribute("style")
el.removeAttribute("style")
```

Jquery wraps browser APIs, so you need to understand those APIs first before trying to understand the behaviors that jQ adds on top of them.

Comment: Okay so this is (sort of) a hack...correct me if I'm wrong. So jQuery .css adds CSS properties in the same way you add inline properties to the "style" attribute directly in the HTML (which is generally frown upon in the CSS community if you do it manually). So now, removeAttr('style') has nothing to do with jQuery, it just says...hey remove this attribute (which jQuery used before to add properties to).